# Unwanted parameters in redirect url after post in Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, redirect, parameters, laravel-8

I add a server with a hostname and an IP address to my database. After that I redirect to my homepage. The url returned in the redirect is correct (http://example.com), but after the user is redirected there are post parameters in the url. I want to redirect without the post parameters. I can't find a solution to my problem. Laravel is version 8.

In controller:

```
if ($validatedData) {
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    HpeServers::create($validatedData);
    return 'Url of the redirect: ' . redirect()->route('ilostatus');
}
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('ilostatus');
})->name('ilostatus');
```

What I get in the console:

```
Url of the redirect: http://example.com
```

```
Redirected to: http://example.com?_token=B3bop5GrknTlcxD5olg0tDh4Fv2FFy9uTblfZuaX&hostname=something.com&ip=1.2.3.4
```

I want the 'redirected to' without parameters, I don't know where they come from. How do I get rid of the parameters? As I understand the initial redirect url is correct, but somewhere unwanted parameters from previous post request are added.

---

Comment: There's no redirect happening in any part of the code you've shared

Comment: Looks like a submitted form with method 'GET'